# APEX dynamic tabular form field types

Tags: oracle-apex, tabular-form

We are populating a subregion of a page with an Iframe (call to another page) with data for a questionnaire.

We have PAGE ITEM variables (`:P37_...` populated by query) that contain table values for `P37_QUESTION_DESCRIPTION`  and `P37_RESPONSE_TYPE`.

The sub page used in the region (`:P28_...`) assigns report attributes for each column... where We populated the question text in the `P28_QUESTION_DESC` and a `Y/N` Select List defined list of values in the `P28_RESPONSE_DESC_DISPLAY` column. This works fine.

Now, the `P37_RESPONSE_TYPE` can more than just this `Y/N` Select List. It could be `TEXTAREA`, `PICKLIST`, `DATE`...

How can we define the `:P28_RESPONSE_DESC_DISPLAY` column dynamically to be any number of user input field types (based on the value in `:P37_REPSONSE_TYPE`?)

Comment: This was solved by using a non-tabular form report generated by query using apex.item functions. But is has left me with another problem. Here's the query:

Comment: Hi Scott. The reason your question has probably been overlooked is because of the wrong tag "apex" which is about the Force.com apex product, and not the oracle one. You also should not answer your question with another question. If you did figure out the answer to your original question, then post a clear answer and accept it yourself. Then create a new question (and you can reference either in both if you desire). That keeps our stacks from overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using a non-tabular form report generated by query using apex.item functions. But is has left me with another problem. Here's the query:

```
select
apex_item.hidden(31,CASE_QUEST_DTL_ID) CASE_QUEST_DTL_ID,
apex_item.hidden(32,CASE_MGMT_BASE_ID) CASE_MGMT_BASE_ID,
apex_item.display_and_save(33,to_number(question_seq_no)) QUESTION_SEQ_NO,
apex_item.display_and_save(34,question_desc) QUESTION_DESC,
case when response_type = 'PICKLIST-YESNO' then apex_item.select_list_from_lov(35,response_desc,'YES_NO_SELECTLIST',NULL,'NO')
     when response_type = 'TEXTFIELD' then apex_item.text(35,response_desc)
     when response_type = 'TEXTAREA' then apex_item.textarea(35,response_desc,5,40)
     when response_type = 'DATEPICKER' then APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(35,to_date(response_desc,'dd-mon-yyyy'),'dd-mon-yyyy')
end RESPONSE_DESC
from V_CASE_QUEST_LINK 
where question_set_code like 'COB_Q%'
and case_mgmt_base_id = :P37_CASE_MGMT_BASE_ID
```

My problem is now grouping the questions by question_set_code. Because GROUP BY is evaluated after the select, it cannot simply be tacked on to the end of the query. I'm not sure that using a nested select will work here because of the apex.item calls. Anyone have a suggestion on how I can group these questions by the column?